# Обращение к View в другом layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-navigation-drawer

Есть `drawer.xml` файл  в котором находятся какие-то `view` и `NavigationView`.

Разметка именно `NavigationView` в `drawer.xml`

```
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"/>
```

как видно, `хередЛайауту` присваивается другой `layout`, в котором содержится `TextView`.

Код `drawer_header.xml`

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@drawable/drawer_header_color"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/number_group"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

В это самое `TextView` я хочу зассетить некоторый текст. Каким образом это можно решить?
В активити в котором я хочу это сделать, корневым `layout` явлется `drawer.xml`
т.е.

```
setContentView(R.layout.drawer);
```

Comment: Разобрался. Сейчас отвечу

Comment: вложенные `View` тек же замечательно находятся при помощи `findViewById()`

Answer (score 1):

Обращайтесь к TextView так же как и к другим View

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText(//Ваш текст//);
```

Пример 
XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="ua.complife.cl_office.MainActivity">
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        tools:openDrawer="start">
        <LinearLayout   
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/header_menu_drawer"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer_items" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Java:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText("Hello");
```

Comment: Если необходимо чтобы вылетел `NullPointerException`, тогда Ваш ответ верен

Comment: Если у вас вложеный Layout в другой, NullPointerException вылетать не будет.

Comment: Вы в вопросе написали, что в NavigationView свойство app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header", а название хедера drawer.xml, они не соответствуют

Comment: да, опечатался. Во всяком случае, вашим способом вылетает `NullPointerException`. Я написал ответ как решил собственную проблему. Попробую еще раз сделать это вашим методом

Comment: Можно так попробовать TextView textView = (TextView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.textView);

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы обратиться к некоторому `View` содержащемуся в некорневом `layout`, являющимся разметкой хедера в `NavigationView` необходимо создать объект класса `View`, определить его, и уже в нем производить поиск. В контексте этого вопроса, решение выглядит следующим образом:

```
    View headerLayout = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.drawer_header); // инфлейтим разметку нашего хедера во время выполнения
    TextView headerTitle = (TextView) headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.textView); // и теперь имеем доступ к любому компоненту в headerLayout
    headerTitle.setText("Некоторый текст");
```

Естественно, что свойство `app:headerLayout` нужно будет убрать, иначе отобразятся 2 хедера